# Python (+django) absent garbage collection in simple script

Tags: python, django, model, garbage-collection

So i have this script in python.
It uses models from django to get some (to be precise: a lot of) data from database.

A quick 'summary' of what i want to achieve (it might be not so important, so you can as well get it just by looking at the code):
There are objects of A type.
For each A object there are related objects of B type (1 to many).
For each B object there are related objects of C type (1 to many).
For each C object there is one related object that is particularly interesting for me- let's call it D (1 to 1 relation).

For each A object in database(not many) i need to get all B objects related to it and all the D objects related to it to create a summary of the A object. Each summary is a separate worksheet (i am using **openpyxl**).

The code i wrote is valid (meaning: it does what i want it to do), but there's problem with garbage collection, so the process gets killed. I have tried not using prefetching, since time is not that much of a concern, but it doesn't really help.

Abstract code:

```
a_objects = A.objects.all()
wb = Workbook()

for a_object in a_objects:
    ws = wb.create_sheet()
    ws.title = a.name
    summary_dictionary = {}
    << 1 >>
    b_objects = B.objects.filter(a_object=a_object)

    for b_object in b_objects:
        c_objects = C.objects.filter(b_object=b_object)
        for c_object in c_objects:
            # Here i put a value in dictionary, or alter it, 
            # depending on whether c_object.d_object has unique fields for current a_object
            # Key is a tuple of 3 floats (taken from d_object)
            # Value is array of 3 small integers (between 0 and 100) 

    summary_dictionary = sorted(summary_dictionary.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))

    for summary_item in summary_dictionary:
        ws.append([summary_item[0][0], summary_item[0][1], summary_item[0][2], summary_item[1][0], summary_item[1][1], summary_item[1][2], sum(summary_item[1])])

wb.save("someFile.xlsx")
```

While theoretically the whole xlsx file could be huge - possibly over 1GB, if all the d_objects values were unique, i estimate it to be a lot under 100 MB even at the end of the script. There's about 650 MB free memory in system while script is being executed.

There are about 80 A objects and the script is killed after 6 or 7 of them. I used "top" to monitor memory usage and didn't notice any memory being freed, which is weird, because, let's say: 
3rd a_object had 1000 b_objects related to it and each b_object had 30 c_objects related to it and
 4th a_object had only 100 b_objects related to it and each b_object had only 2 c_objects related to it.

A lot of memory should be freed some time after <<1>> in 4th iteration, right?

My point is that what i thought this program should behave like, is that it would run as long as the following can fit into memory:
- the whole summary
- a single set of all b_objects and its c_objects and its d_objects for any a_object in database.

What am i missing then?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching:

```
a_objects = A.objects.all()
```

to:

```
a_objects = A.objects.all().iterator()
```

Comment: I will give it a try tommorow, and with other objects( b and c), since a is of the least significance here (there are only about 80 of them)

Comment: Also, i don't really understand how would it help. I know iterator prevents caching, but cached objects should be garbage collected when the reference to queryset is deleted after <<1>>, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To collect the ESSP system.fstat metrics set with Fluent Bit we need to create a custom Python collection script.

Comment: Is this answer meant for this question or is it accidentally posted here?